# Invalid Data After Declaration - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm not sure where my error is.  I declare two labels in my kv file.  The first one works fine, but the second catches an error "Invalid data after declaration."  Here's the code in my kv file:

```
<LoadingScreen>:
    elsaLabel: label
    Label
        id: label
        text: "ELSA"
        font_size: 80
        color: 0.28, 0.69, 0.77, 1
        opacity: 0

    startLabel: label
    Label
        id: start
        text: "Welcome"
        font_size: 25
        color: 0.28, 0.69, 0.77, 1
        opacity: 0
        pos: 0, -150
```

The error occurs on the line "startLabel: label".  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file), the properties (`elsaLabel` and `startLabel`) should appear before the children Widgets. Try moving `startLabel: label` to before the first `Label` rule.